# Power output of a decelerating body

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

Consider something like a car, which has some initial velocity, $v$. When the brake is pressed, the car experiences a braking force, $F$. (Ignore other forces such as friction and air resistance). The constant braking force means that the car experiences constant deceleration.

My question is: Does this mean that the power output of the engine falls as it decelerates? Since the work done by the engine in one second is $Fv$, and $v$ becomes smaller and smaller, it seems like the car engine's power output falls too.

Comment: The power output of the engine does not depend on the car speed, but rather on the engine speed.

Answer (score 2):

Typically, you would depress the clutch when braking so that the engine was no longer connected to the wheels.  Any power it is producing will be waste e.g. heat and noise.

If you leave the engine engaged and brake against it then a lot the power will go into heating the brakes (in addition to the power coming from reducing the car's kinetic energy).

Answer (score 0):

"the work done by the engine in one second is $Fv$" --- assuming your $F$ still means the braking force, then no, it is not $Fv$.  The engine drives the wheels through a series of gears; what actually defines its output power is its output torque and speed of rotation.

Answer (score 0):

If v becomes smaller then F becomes smaller which means that the overall work decreases as well. Therefore if Power = Work / time, proves that your power falls too.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

The expression for power is $$ P = F v = m \,v \,a $$ where $m$ is mass, $v$ is speed and $a$ is acceleration (or decceleration).

- **Acceleration**

  This is interpreted as $$ a= \frac{P}{m v}$$ for an accelerating car, where the rate of acceleration is derived from the engine power output divided by the momentum of the car. The engine power depended on the engine speed, and hence if you are in high gear (and low rpm) you cannot produce as much power as in low gear (and high rpm).
- **Deccelertion**

  When the brakes are applied they absorb an enormous amount of power equal to $$P = m\, v\, a$$ initially if the car is moving fast. As it slows down the power absorption rate goes down. This is why brakes will glow red when braking from high speeds. All the power (and energy) becomes heat in the braking system.